# not reading the first line

Tags: c++, file, vector, getline

I was using the following code to read information from a file (b.txt) into a vector.
every time I execute, the program starts reading from the second line.
So vector_b[0] = the second line instead of the first line.

I'm still not used to c++
hope you can help

```
string line_b;
int idx = -1;
float *vector_b = new float[1];
float element_b;
if (file_b.is_open() && file_b.good()) {
    cout << "File is open. \n";
    while (getline(file_b, line_b)) {
        stringstream stream_b(line_b);
        while(1) {
            stream_b >> element_b;
            if(!stream_b) {
                break; }
            idx = idx+1;
            float *tempArr = new float [idx];
            copy(vector_b, vector_b + idx, tempArr);
            tempArr[idx] = element_b;
            delete [] vector_b;
            vector_b = tempArr;
        }
    }        
    } 
    else {
        cout << "Failed to open file.";
    }
```

Comment: You might want to consider using `std::vector<float>` instead of `new`.

Comment: I'm not that keen on c++ , can you tell me how to use std::vector<float> in the code above

Comment: Declaration:  `std::vector<float> container;`.  Extraction: `float a = container[3];`.  Insertion: `container.push_back(3.14159264);`

Comment: Just posed my answer. If anything doesn't make sense, just let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try something like the following. You might try a `vector` as opposed to a dynamic array. they're more flexible and in most cases faster. You don't have to worry about use after frees, double frees, or memory leaks... so Yeah... vectors rule...

```
int main() {
    std::ifstream file_b;
    file_b.open("Some-file.cpp");

    std::string line_b;
    // vector_b is a vector of doubles
    std::vector<double> vector_b();
    double element_b;
    if (file_b.is_open() && file_b.good()) {
        std::cout << "File is open. \n" << std::endl;
        while(getline(file_b, line_b)) {
            std::stringstream stream_b(line_b);
            // You don't need a second if.
            while(stream_b) {
                stream_b >> element_b;
                // append element_b to your vector
                vector_b.push_back(element_b);
            }
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

However, if you can't use vectors, I'd suggest you look into creating a container class like the class and usage listed below. I don't trust myself to remember to free memory, so sometimes its just best to build a class. I tested the class below under valgrind a few times, so there shouldn't be any leaks, but no promises. I made it very hurried.

```
#include <cassert>

// use a templated class so we can use it with different types
template<typename T>
class Container {
    private:
        unsigned int m_size;
        unsigned int m_capacity;
        T* m_array;

    public:
        // Any time you make a container class make sure you follow the
        // rule of 5 with C++11 or the rule of 3 for prior compilers
        // 1) Copy Constructor
        // 2) Move Constructor (C++11)
        // 3) Copy Assignment Operator
        // 4) Move Assignment Operator (C++11)
        // 5) Destructor

        // Default constructor
        Container() { }

        // Constructor we'll use
        Container(unsigned sz) :
            m_size(0),
            m_capacity(sz),
            m_array(new T[sz]) { }

        // Copy constructor
        Container(const Container& src) :
            m_size(src.m_size),
            m_capacity(src.m_size),
            m_array(new T[src.m_size]) {
                for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_size; ++i) {
                    // copy values
                    m_array[i] = src.m_array[i];
                }
            }

        // Move constructor
        Container(Container&& src) {
            // "steal" the sources members
            m_capacity = src.m_capacity;
            m_size = src.m_size;
            m_array = src.m_array;
            // "destroy" the sources members
            src.m_size = 0;
            src.m_capacity = 0;
            src.m_array = nullptr;
        }

        // Destructor
        ~Container() {
            delete[] m_array;
        }

        // Copy assignment operator
        Container& operator=(const Container& src) {
            // check to make sure you're copying a different source
            if(this == &src) {
                return *this;
            }
            // free your current memory
            delete[] m_array;
            // make a new array and copy the sources values
            m_array = new T[src.m_size];
            for(unsigned i = 0; i < src.m_size; ++i) {
                m_array[i] = src.m_array[i];
            }
            // copy the size parameters
            m_size = src.m_size;
            m_capacity = src.m_capacity;
            return(*this);
        }

        // Move assignment operator
        Container& operator=(Container&& src) {
            // check to make sure you're copying a different source
            if(this == &src) {
                return *this;
            }
            // free your current memory
            delete[] m_array;
            // "steal" the sources members
            m_array = src.m_array;
            m_size = src.m_size;
            m_capacity = src.m_capacity;
            // "destroy" the sources members
            src.m_array = nullptr;
            src.m_size = 0;
            src.m_capacity = 0;
            return(*this);
        }

        void resize(unsigned int sz) {
            // make sure you're not shrinking the container
            if(sz > m_capacity) {
                // make a temporary array
                T* tmp = new T[sz];
                for(unsigned i = 0; i < m_size; ++i) {
                    // copy the values to the temporary array
                    tmp[i] = m_array[i];
                }
                // free your current memory
                delete[] m_array;
                // "steal" the temporary array
                m_array = tmp;
                // release tmp's handle on the memory
                tmp = nullptr;
                // inform your object that it has more memory now
                m_capacity = sz;
            }
        }

        void push_back(const T& src) {
            // check if you have enough space to append a value
            if(m_size + 1 > m_capacity) {
                // if not, double your current size, so you don't have
                // to do it every time
                resize((m_capacity + 1) * 2);
            }
            // increment the size member and append the value to your array
            m_array[m_size++] = src;
        }

        T& operator[](unsigned index) {
            // make sure the index value is in-bounds
            assert(index < m_size);
            return(m_array[index]);
        }

        size_t size() { return(m_size); }
};
```

Usage:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Container<std::string> vector_b(1);
    std::ifstream file_b;
    file_b.open("Sleep.cpp");

    std::string line_b;
    std::string element_b;
    if (file_b.is_open() && file_b.good()) {
        std::cout << "File is open. \n" << std::endl;
        while(getline(file_b, line_b)) {
            std::stringstream stream_b(line_b);
                while(stream_b) {
                    stream_b >> element_b;
                    vector_b.push_back(element_b);
                }
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "Failed to open file." << std::endl;;
    }

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < vector_b.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << vector_b[i] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

As you can see, working with dynamic memory allocations is a pain, and generally should be avoided, or at least handled with extreme care and lots of valgrind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer…
but I’m only allowed to use “dynamic memory allocation”.
So , What is the problem with the code I have used?

Comment: I'll update the answer, but honestly if you've got to do dynamic memory allocation, you might be better off building a container class, which is what I'll update in the answer

Comment: I made the necessary edits. If this works, make sure to mark this question as answered

Comment: If you're using this you may want to check my code. I just realized I forgot to `return *this;` on the assignment operators. I mad the necessary edits.